# ElasticSearch reindex nested field as new documents

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, reindex

I am currently changing my ElasticSearch schema.
I previously had one type `Product` in my index with a nested field `Product.users`.
And I now wants to get 2 different indices, one for `Product`, an other one for `User` and make links between both in code.

I use `reindex` API to reindex all my `Product` documents to the new index, removing the `Product.users` field using script:

> ctx._source.remove('users');

But I don't know how to reindex all my `Product.users` documents to the new `User` index as in script I'll get an ArrayList of `users` and I want to create one `User` document for each.

Does anyone knows how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may face this situation, I finally ended up reindexing `users` nested field using both `scroll` and `bulk` APIs.

- I used `scroll` API to get batches of `Product` documents
- For each batch iterate over those `Product` documents
- For each document iterate over `Product.users`
- Create a new `User` document and add it to a bulk
- Send the bulk when I end iterating over `Product` batch

Doing the job <3

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called ETL (Extract, Transform, Load).

Most the time, this is more handy to write a small python script that does exactly what you want, but, with elasticsearch, there is one I love: Apache Spark + elasticsearch4hadoop plugin.

Also, sometime logstash can do the trick, but with Spark you have:

- SQL syntax or support Java/Scala/Python code
- read/write elasticsearch very fast because distributed worker (1 ES shard = 1 Spark worker)
- fault tolerant (a worker crash ? no problem)
- clustering (ideal if you have billion of documents)

Use with Apache Zeppelin (a notebook with Spark packaged & ready), you will love it!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is to run the reindex command twice. Once selecting the Product fields and re indexing into the newProduct index and once for the user:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "Product",
    "type": "_doc",
    "_source": ["fields", "to keep in", "new Products"]
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_Products"
  }
}
```

Then you should be able to do the re-index again on the new_User table by selecting Product.users only in the 2nd re-index